# How do you increment a number with every table row?

Tags: php, mysql

It is very simple, but I cannot do it. Now it takes every information from my database and introduces it in the Nr. td. How can I increment the value with every row?

```
<?php while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td (this is what I want to auto-increment)>

                <?php
                    $i = 1;
                    foreach($row as $i){
                    $i++;
                    echo $i;
                    }
                ?>

            </td>
            <td width="120">

                <?php echo $row['Name'];?>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
<?php } ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: huh! what exactly you want to do?!

Comment: In a td I want to have numbers for each row: 1,2,3 .... as long as I have rows. But I don't know any php..

Comment: Please note that mysql_* functions are unsafe and deprecated. you need to start looking into PDO (or mysqli)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

Modify your code as given below:

```
<tbody>

<?php 
$i = 1;
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td width="5">
                <?php
                    echo $i;
                    $i++;
                ?>

            </td>
            <td width="120">

                <?php echo $row['Name'];?>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php }?>

    </tbody>
```

Comment: There is one closing bracket too much.

Comment: @danutclaudiu. Pl accept so others will also get help.

Comment: This will work for table without pagination, but when you add pagination the number always starts from 1 in 2, 3, 4... pages. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Initialize $i before the `while loop` then echo in the td then increment it.

```
<?php 
$i=1;
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td width="5">

            <?php
                echo $i;
                $i++;
                //You can join the above 2 lines into 1 like this:
                // echo $i++;
                // This way you're telling php, echo $i then increment it by 1
            ?>

        </td>
        <td width="120">

            <?php echo $row['Name'];?>

        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<?php } ?>
```

**NB: if you're just learning PHP, you shouldn't be learning mysql_* as they are deprecated and will be removed in future releases. Check out [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/PDO).**

Comment: `<? echo $i++; ?>` could be nicer.

Comment: @D.Kasipovic just wanted it to be clear for him, as I saw he's starting to learn...

Answer (score 0):

initialize

> $i = 1;

outside while loop

> while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))

, so that it will increase.

Answer (score 0):

Have your row counter (`$rowNum`) outside of the while

```
 <?php 
    $rowNum = 1; ?>


     <tbody>
         <?php while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
         <tr>
             <td width="5">
                 <?php echo $rowNum; $rowNum++ ?>
             </td>
             <td width="120">

                 <?php echo $row['Name'];?>

             </td>
         </tr>
         <?php } ?>
     </tbody>
```